# Yii framework: importing classes while in the config/main.php file

Tags: class, yii, config, alias, import

Trying to import a class while in `config/main.php` (*before* the Yii configuration is returned):

```
 //class LanguageSettings is placed directly in protected/components/LanguageSettings.php
 Yii::import('application.components.*');
 LanguageSettings::currentLanguage();
```

causes that fatal error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 
 'Alias "application.components.*" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing 
 directory or file.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php:
```

Why ? Can Yii resolve the alias correctly before importing the configuration array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I do not think it will work because the basePath has not been set yet, therefore Yii cannot calculate where application.components.* is referring to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any other way the path can be imported (manually)?

Comment: Well, since usually basePath (in config/main.php) is defined as dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..' you can define it in a variable ($myBasePath) at the top of main.php and then manually do import_once($myBasePath . '/components/myComponent.php') bypassing the autoimport functionality of Yii.  Kinda hacky, though...

Comment: Hacky but helpful. Thank you ! 
ps. import_once = include / require_once.